# jquery draggable on few divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Picture:
[image]

```
<div id="grid-wrapper">
<div id="grid"></div>
<div id="grid"></div>
<div id="grid"></div>
<div id="grid"></div>
</div>
```

I want to change class on two divs when I drop my span, and remove draggable.

I have this:

```
$( ".dragandrop" ).draggable({ snap: "#grid" });

    $("#grid").droppable({
          drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
              .addClass( "droped" )
          }
        });
```

This code add me .droppable only on first div, and doesn't add class "droped", I can't do removing .draggable. Can you help me?

Comment: IDs need to be **unique**; You can't give all those elements the same ID. Use a class instead.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but still I can't drop element on two divs

Answer (score 0):

First off, be careful using the same id for multiple elements. It can cause really weird issues (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-types)).

Second, make sure you add the *draganddrop* class to the appropriate elements that you want to, well, drag and drop.

And you want to removed the draggable on an element once you dropped it? I think what you want looks something like this:

```js
$( ".dragandrop" ).draggable({ 
    snap: ".dragandrop" ,
    stop: function(event, ui){
        $( this ).addClass( "droped" );
        $( this ).draggable( 'disable' );
    }
});

$(".dragandrop").droppable({});
```

```css
div{
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid-wrapper">
   <div id="grid1" style="background:orange;" class="dragandrop">a</div>
   <div id="grid2" style="background:red;" class="dragandrop">b</div>
   <div id="grid3" style="background:green;" class="dragandrop">c</div>
   <div id="grid4" style="background:yellow;" class="dragandrop">d</div>
</div>
```

You may also want to add in some logic to keep the active div on top.